# writing the strcat function with pointers

Tags: c++

I am trying to write the `strcat` function with basic c++ functionality. So far I came up with this: I wrote a function to do the job and it returns a pointer:

```
char * stuff (char *s1, const char *s2);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char array[10] = "hello";
    char array2[30] = "good morning";
    char *array3 = new char[50];
    array3 = stuff(array, array2);
    while (*array3 != '\0')
    {
        cout << *array3;
        array3++;
    }
}

char * stuff(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *p = s1;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        p++;
    }
    while (*s2 != '\0')
    {
        *p = *s2;

        p++;
        s2++;
    }
    return s1;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this code with basic programming. I currently don't get any outputs with this code and I think the issue is with how I call the function but I am not sure.

i found out my mistake, i should have just printed the first array cause it is adding the second array to the first array.

Comment: `std::string(array) + array2` would do the job.

Comment: @Bathsheba i am trying to use cstring

Comment: Why is that? That's a bit like buying a car then pushing it along, or attaching a horse to it, rather than driving it.

Comment: @Bathsheba: On the other hand, a car manufacturer has to know how a car works inside.

Comment: And to do that, you'd look inside the car (cf. C++ standard library) rather than looking inside the horse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are modifying `array`, but not `array3`. `array` has only place for 9 characters (+ final zero byte).

Comment: And note that the implementation of `stuff` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to your question:**

Your program should be like this:

```
char * stuff (char *s1, const char *s2);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char array[50] = "hello";           // make sure array has enough space
    char array2[30] = "good morning";
    stuff(array, array2);
    cout << array;                      // you can output char array directly, no need to traverse
}

char * stuff(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *p = s1;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        p++;
    }

    while (*s2 != '\0')
    {
        *p++ = *s2++;
    }
    return s1;
}
```

**Other problems with your code:**

```
char *array3 = new char[50];
array3 = stuff(array, array2);
```

This is not right. You allocated memory for `array3`, yet you didn't use it. When you assign new value to `array3`, the 50 bytes memory was leaked.

Comment: The question is about implementing `strcat`; `strcat` takes two arguments, not three, so this change doesn't answer the question.